# How to display custom post type in a submenu?

Tags: menu, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am adding a submenu named as "Articles" using add_submenu_page() under a custom menu.
I want to display the custom post type="page_article" in this "Articles" submenu.

Whenever I click on Articles submenu , it should redirect me to "edit.php?post_type="page_article".

I have tried with wp_redirect in callback function of add_submenu_page, but I am not getting.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably i think you want to add a custom type post as sub-menu in WordPress dashboard.
You can do.

```
 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );
 function my_plugin_menu(){
   add_menu_page('Page title', 'Top-level menu title', 'manage_options',  'my-top-level-handle', 'my_menu_function');
   add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-handle', 'Custom Post Type Admin', 'Articles', 'manage_options','edit.php?post_type=page_article');
 }
```

Don't forget to add below code while registering a custom type post

```
 'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=page_article'
```

Comment: But its not working to get custom admin submenu( custom post type ) item to highlight when its active.

Comment: For active menu link plz [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927445/wordpress-admin-when-placing-a-custom-post-type-as-a-submenu-of-a-parent-menu)

Comment: The 'show_in_menu' makes the submenu to be current/highlighted when the 'my_post_type' is on the admin-screen. But my parent menu stayed inactive, so I had to add also:: add_filter( 'parent_file', 'menu_highlight' )); And:: function menu_highlight( $parent_file ){ global $plugin_page, $post_type; if ('my_post_type' == $post_type) { $plugin_page = 'edit.php?post_type=my_post_type';}   return $parent_file; }

Comment: Any idea how would you do the same for custom taxonomies?